# Matrix scalar multiplication

Tags: python

Is there a more 'mathematical' way to do the following:

```
1.2738 * (list_of_items)
```

So for what I'm doing is:

```
[1.2738 * item for item in list_of_items]
```

Comment: What is the problem with the way you are doing it now? Is there a problem? Sure, you could use numpy or some other tricks but your solution seems pretty concise to me.

Comment: No — lists are heterogeneous collections and thus can contain elements of many dissimilar types, so they don't have a built-in multiply-each-element-by-a-scalar method or operator.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The mathematical equivalent of what you're describing is the operation of multiplication by a scalar for a vector. Thus, my suggestion would be to convert your list of elements into a "vector" and then multiply that by the scalar.

A standard way of doing that would be using `numpy`.

Instead of

```
1.2738 * (list_of_items)
```

You can use

```
import numpy
1.2738 * numpy.array(list_of_items)
```

Sample Output:

```
In [8]: list_of_items
Out[8]: [1, 2, 4, 5]

In [9]: import numpy

In [10]: 1.2738 * numpy.array(list_of_items)
Out[10]: array([ 1.2738,  2.5476,  5.0952,  6.369 ])
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach

```
map(lambda x:x*1.2738,list_of_items)
```